# Why applying "factor" changes the result of `table` command

Tags: r

I am using data frame, named `sells`, and uploaded to this link http://www.filedropper.com/weekpurchases18-25

It has a column called `TitleCli`, I correct its value like this:

```
> library(stringr)
> sells$TitleCli <- str_trim(sells$TitleCli)
```

I have another column called `Gender`, which I fill it like this:

```
ifelse(sells$TitleCli == "MR", sells$Gender<-"F", "M")
```

The result of that command is this:

```
[1] "M" "M" "M" "F" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M"
 [21] "F" "M" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "M" "M" "M" "F" "M" "M" "F" "F"
 [41] "F" "M" "M" "F" "F" "M" "F" "F" "F" "F" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "F" "M" "F" "M" "F"
 [61] "M" "F" "M" "F" "M" "F" "M" "M" "F" "M" "M" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "M" "M" "M" "M"
 [81] "F" "F" "M" "F" "M" "M" "M" "F" "F" "F" "F" "M" "M" "F" "M" "M" "F" "M" "F" "F"
[101] "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "F" "F" "M" "M" "F" "M" "F" "M"
[121] "M" "F" "F" "F" "F" "M" "M" "F" "F" "M" "M" "F" "M" "M" "F" "F" "M" "M" "F" "M"
[141] "M" "M" "M" "F" "F" "M" "M" "M" "F" "M" "M" "M" "F" "M" "M" "M" "F" "M" "F" "F"
[161] "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "F" "M" "F" "M" "F" "M" "M" "F" "F" "M" "M" "M" "F" "F" "M"
[181] "F" "F" "M" "F" "F" "F" "M" "M" "M" "M" "F" "F" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M"
[201] "M" "F" "F" "M" "F" "F" "M" "M" "M" "F" "F" "M" "F" "M" "F" "M" "M" "F" "M" "M"
[221] "M" "F" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "F" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M"
[241] "F" "F" "M" "F" "F" "M" "M" "F" "F" "M" "M" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "M" "M" "M" "M"
[261] "M" "M" "M" "M" "F" "M" "F" "F" "M" "F" "M" "M" "M" "F" "M" "F" "F" "M" "F" "F"
[281] "F" "M" "F" "F" "F" "M" "M" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "M" "M" "F" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M"
[301] "M" "F" "F" "F" "F" "M" "F" "F" "F" "M" "M" "M" "F" "M" "F" "M" "M" "M" "M" "F"
[321] "F" "M" "F" "F" "F" "F" "M" "F" "F" "M" "M" "F" "F" "M" "F" "M" "M" "M" "F" "F"
[341] "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "F" "M" "F" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "F" "F" "M" "M" "M" "F" "M"
[361] "F" "F" "M" "F" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "F" "M" "M" "F" "M" "M" "M"
[381] "F" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "F" "M" "M" "M" "M" "F" "M" "M" "M" "F" "M" "F" "F" "F"
[401] "F" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "F" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "F" "M" "F" "F" "F"
[421] "F" "F" "F" "M" "F" "M" "F" "M" "M" "M" "M" "F" "F" "M" "F" "M" "M" "F" "M" "F"
[441] "M" "F" "M" "F" "F" "M" "F" "M" "F" "M" "F" "F" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "F" "F"
[461] "F" "F" "F" "M" "F" "F" "F" "F" "M" "M" "F" "M" "F" "F" "F" "M" "M" "F" "F" "F"
[481] "F" "F" "M" "M" "M" "F" "F" "M" "M" "M" "F" "M" "M" "M" "M" "F" "F" "M" "F" "F"
[501] "F" "F" "F" "F" "M" "M" "M" "F" "M" "M" "M" "M" "F" "M" "F" "F" "F" "M" "M" "M"
[521] "M" "F" "F" "M" "F" "F" "F" "F" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "F" "F" "M" "M" "M" "F" "M"
[541] "M" "F" "M" "M" "F" "M" "M" "F" "M" "F" "M" "F" "M" "M" "F" "M" "M" "F" "M" "M"
[561] "F" "M" "F" "F" "M" "M" "F" "M" "F" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "F"
[581] "F" "F" "F" "M" "F" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "F" "M" "M" "F" "F" "M"
[601] "F" "F" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "F" "M" "M" "F" "M" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "M" "F" "M"
[621] "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "F" "F" "F" "M" "F" "M" "F" "F" "M" "F" "F" "M" "F" "F"
[641] "M" "F" "F" "F" "M" "M" "M" "M" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "M" "M" "F" "F" "F" "F" "M"
[661] "M" "M" "M" "F" "M" "M" "M" "F" "F" "F" "M" "F" "F" "F" "M" "M" "M" "M" "F" "M"
[681] "F" "F" "M" "M" "F" "M" "F" "F" "M" "M" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "M" "M" "M" "F" "M"
[701] "M" "M" "F" "F" "M" "F" "M" "M" "F" "M" "F" "F" "M" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "M" "F"
[721] "F" "F" "F" "F" "M" "M" "F" "F" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "F" "M" "F" "M" "F" "F"
```

as you see, the data contains "M", and "F"

**My confusion** is when I did this: `table(sells$Gender)` I got this:

```
F 
739
```

which means all the lines are `F` because the number of the lines is `739`

**I solved** that by accident doing this:

```
sells$Gender <- factor(ifelse(sells$TitleCli=="MR","M","F"))
```

after doing that accident solution, i did this:  `table(sells$Gender)` and the result was as expected

```
F   M 
413 326
```

**My question** is why it didn't work before applying the `factor` and why did it work after it

Thanks

Comment: Your first command looks different`ifelse(sells$TitleCli == "MR", sells$Gender<-"F", "M")` than the one you used later `ifelse(sells$TitleCli=="MR","M","F")`

Comment: Your use of `ifelse` is wrong. It should look like `sells$Gender <- ifelse(sells$TitleCli == "MR", "F", "M")`.

Comment: @akrun your notice may explain why the `table(sells$Gender)` command gives the correct result in the second time. However, i still need to know why my first command, which is `ifelse(sells$TitleCli=="Mr", sells$Gender<-).....` didn't work correctly as it should

Comment: As @Roland mentioned it is wrong way of using the `ifelse`.

Comment: @Roland thanks for this new information for me, but please what is the difference? what does my command mean then? and why the `table` command gives me just `M` when I apply my command?

Comment: @Roland even when I tried your command as this: `sells$Gender <- ifelse(sells$TitleCli == "Mr", "M", "F")` and then I checked the table like this `table(sells$Gender)` the result is `F  739`, just the `F`. the `M ` didn't appear

Comment: @akrun I tried the commad of `Roland` and It didn't work, I described what happened in the above comment

Comment: If you do `ifelse(sells$TitleCli == "MR", sells$Gender<-"F", "M")` you first assign `F` to `sells$Gender`. This returns `sells$Gender` and is used within `ifelse`. However, the return value of `ifelse` you don't assign.

Comment: Note that first you compare with "MR", but later on with "Mr". Which is it?

Comment: @PaolaRLang I tried `set.seed(24);v1 <- sample(c('MR', 'MF', 'MT'), 20, replace=TRUE); table(ifelse(v1=='MR', 'M', 'F'))` gives both F and M

Comment: @Roland yes my friend, that was my typo. now it is working when i assign "M" directly to `sells$Gender`. However, I didn't get you 100% when you described the difference between my *wrong*, *previous* way and your correct way. May you explain when an example please